# Find which process is responsible for a DNS request

Tags: networking, macos, dns, pihole

I started using [Pi-hole](https://pi-hole.net/) recently to block ads on all home devices (including my Macbook).

Looking at the logs today, I noticed many weird DNS requests originating from my Macbook to seemingly random hostnames that end with `.home` like `etpqdghkdm.home`, and every domain is requested just once.

I also found many requests to regular `.com` hostnames that appear to be (judging by Google search) ad services. I started blocking them one by one but then figured out it's going to be an endless task. They are many of them that I think knowing the app/process requesting them and blocking/removing it would be better.

The problem is I didn't find any way to know who exactly is responsible for every DNS request. I'm already using [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) to monitor network traffic on my Macbook, but it doesn't help here.

I thought that installing a custom DNS server on my Macbook may help in logging DNS requests and knowing the culprit process(es), but I'm not sure if this could work and how can I do it.

**EDIT:**

I [found out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363512/chrome-dns-requests-with-random-dns-names-malware) that Chrome is actually the source for those random hostnames, but I still need a way to know who is requesting the other normal hostnames.

Comment: While I don't know how to match up packets to processes, the eventual result will most likely point to a web browser, or an app built around a web engine. These random names are used to detect NXDOMAIN hijacking.

Comment: Yes, you're right about those random hostnames. The source appears to be Chrome in my case (I edited the question). But I still need a way to know who is requesting the other normal and real hostnames.

Answer (score 1):

In little snitch you should be able to view the network monitor and search for the host name and/or the resolves IP. It should show the mdns process which you are aware of, however any other app or process on your system connected to that process should also be listed.  If you can’t find it, you can set up a temporary little snitch setup to “ask” for EVERY single connection approval. It’s kind of time consuming and annoying however it will pinpoint exactly what’s going on. Make sure you have show detailed information (process & port) and selected.

Comment: I already checked Little Snitch but found nothing. It looks like it doesn't log DNS queries.